# fail to open a txt file in my working directory by script in R studio

Tags: r

There is an error while I want to create txt file by script in R studio.I don't really understand the description of the error.

[image: The code and the error]

My classmate has no problem to run the code.

Comment: Your filename does not contain a path, so it must reside in the working directory (`getwd()`) of your R session: check with `dir()` if that's the case. Also check if the file is in open in some other application (e.g. a text editor to inspect the results). If so, close the file in the other application as this might block write access to myframe.txt.

Comment: @I_O I have tried so I guess that is not the problem of file location. As many answer in other similiar error on forum,that might be the problem of permission.I have checked the permission of the file. It is allowed to be amended. However, the code is still with same error. I am almost collapsed on this such kind of tiny issue.Anyway,thanks for your effort.

Comment: @I_O hmm,i dont know what have happened ,i run them in rgui,then it works. thank you very much

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)